# slideToggle on menu item not working

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have a menu that I'd like to drop down when hovering over some text. It's basically a menu for my photography archive. I can't seem to pinpoint why it's not working. Can anyone help?

Here is jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mattj06/NQ4R4/1/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Update your code to:

```
$('.archive-menu-inner').hide();
$('.hover').hover(function() {
    $('.archive-menu-inner').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/zenopopovici/NQ4R4/6/

Answer (score 1):

I think that should do

```
$(function(){
    $('.archive-menu-inner').hide();
    $('.hover').hover(function() {
        $('.archive-menu-inner').slideToggle('fast');
    }, function() {
        $('.archive-menu-inner').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome - Ok now I've implemented into my test page but it's not working. I'm getting this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL. This is actually a common thing with me and I can never figure out this error! It's driving me nuts. Test Page - http://theflyphoto.com/archive-menu.html

Comment: I just found some illegal characters in your code, I don't know why, but firebug shows me it: });â€‹â€‹</script>
On your code..

Comment: Could this be from copy/pasting from jsfiddle? Any idea on how to get rid of this?